# why the php foreach loop is not running with multi-dimentional json object

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am not reaching inside the php foreach loop.

```
$cogsAmount = '[{"name":"cogItem","amount":2},{"name":"cogItem","amount":2}]';
$multipleCogsAccount = '{"cog1":"1","cog2":"2"}';
if ($cogsAmount && count($cogsAmount) > 0) {
    foreach ($cogsAmount as $key => $cog) {
         $cogName = $cog['name'];
         if (!array_key_exists($cogName, $multipleCogsAccount)) {
              echo "The key is not exist";
              
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: PHP would have told you what’s wrong already, if only you had proper error reporting enabled.

Comment: Use [json_decode](https://www.php.net/json_decode) to turn it into an array of objects

Comment: json_decode worked @aynber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's a string! This is a non-iterable object

```
<?php

$cogsAmount = json_decode('[{"name":"cogItem","amount":2},{"name":"cogItem","amount":2}]', 1);

$multipleCogsAccount = json_decode('{"cog1":"1","cog2":"2"}', 1);
if ($cogsAmount && count($cogsAmount) > 0) {
    foreach ($cogsAmount as $key => $cog) {
         echo $cogName = $cog['name'];
         //if (!array_key_exists($cogName, $multipleCogsAccount)) {
         //     echo "The key is not exist";
              
         //}
    }
}
```

Comment: i have tried to json encode it too. But didn't worked

Comment: yes @Александр Черножуков Thanks. Also aynber suggested the same

Answer (score 1):

This works, if you json_decode() those strings

```
$cogsAmount = json_decode('[{"name":"cogItem1","amount":2},{"name":"cogItem2","amount":2}]',true);
$multipleCogsAccount = json_decode('{"cog1":"1","cog2":"2"}',true);
if ($cogsAmount && count($cogsAmount) > 0) {
    foreach ($cogsAmount as $key => $cog) {
         
         if (!array_key_exists($cog['name'], $multipleCogsAccount)) {
              echo "The key $cog[name] does not exist\n";
              
         }
    }
}
```

RESULT

```
The key cogItem1 does not exist
The key cogItem2 does not exist
```